# At least One Check box should be checked in gridview rows using javascript function not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Check box validation checking problem in gridview rows

Hi I was written js function  like bellow it will be used to check at least one check box should be checked in side gridview rows ,  before going to click on submit button this code was working fine In IE but fails to do in Firefox and chrome , can any one tell me where was wrong? .

Hers is the function

```
function ClientCheck() {
    var valid = false;
    var gv = document.getElementById("ctl00_cplContent_gvCurrenttarrif");   
    for (var i = 0; i < gv.all.length; i++) {
        var node = gv.all[i];
        if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!valid) {
        alert("Invalid. Please select a checkbox to continue with changes.");
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique on the page. Instead of "document.getElementById", try to use document.getElementsByClassName ...

Answer (score 1):

[Element.all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not standard so you should not use it. 
Use [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) instead.

Change your code like following.

```
function ClientCheck() {
    var valid = false;
    var gv = document.getElementById("ctl00_cplContent_gvCurrenttarrif");   
    for (var i = 0; i < gv.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = gv.childNodes[i];
        if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!valid) {
        alert("Invalid. Please select a checkbox to continue with changes.");
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Solution for this check here : http://forums.asp.net/t/1932293.aspx/1?Check+box+validation+checking+problem+in+gridview+rows+

Answer (score 0):

Better you use jQuery or similar library for accessing DOM elements.

e.g. Using jquery

```
var checkedBoxesCount = $("<%=gvCurrenttarrif.ClientID%>").find("input:checkbox:checked").length;
if(checkedBoxesCount==0) alert("NO CHECKBOX SELECTED");
```

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting the comment [ramakrishna-p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614691/ramakrishna-p) as answer:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1932293.aspx?Check+box+validation+checking+problem+in+gridview+rows+

Working code is :

```
function ClientCheck() {
    var valid = false;
    var gv = document.getElementById("ctl00_cplContent_gvCurrenttarrif");
    for (var i = 0; i < gv.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
        var node = gv.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
        if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!valid) {
        alert("Invalid. Please select a checkbox to continue with changes.");
    }
    return valid;
}
```